# iPhone - setNeedsDisplay doesn't call drawRect

Tags: iphone, drawrect

I have seen many posts about this problem but didn't get an answer. I have a controller which view is added to the main window. The controller's view has a subview which has a drawRect. The problem is that this function is never called even if I call [self setNeedsDisplay].

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` right? Make sure the method signature is correct, and you don't omit the `rect` argument even if you don't use it.

`-setNeedsDisplay` should be called the the subview, not `self`.

Also, `-setNeedsDisplay` won't call `-drawRect:` immediately. It only flushes the graphics cache so that `-drawRect:` is forced to be called in the next update of the frame.