# setNeedsDisplay revisited

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uibutton, drawrect

I have the often discussed drawRect not getting called.  I've been through many posts, but have not resolved my issue.

The solution is often described as calling `-setNeedsDisplay`.   The answer to question 
[setNeedsDisplay doesn't call drawRect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744857/iphone-setneedsdisplay-doesnt-call-drawrect)  indicates calling it on the subview not `self`.

I have created a subview to draw on a button.  The button is selected.

```
- (IBAction) selected1:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"selected1");    
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender; 
    [button setTitle:@"Chosen1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

 // UsableMark *um = [[UsableMark alloc] init ]; // Original
 // UsableMark *um = [[UsableMark alloc] initWithFrame:button.frame]; // 1st fix
    CGRect umFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,button.frame.size.width,button.frame.size.height); // 2nd fix
    UsableMark *um = [[UsableMark alloc] initWithFrame:umFrame ]; // 2nd fix

    [button addSubview:um];
    [um setNeedsDisplay];
    [um release];    
    button.enabled = NO;    
    NSLog(@"finished selected1");
}
```

A drawRect call in UsableMark is not triggered.
Replacing the  `[um setNeedsDisplay]` with `[button setNeedsDisplay]` does not trigger a drawRect call.
An attempt at using `self` fails because the selected1 method is a class of type UIApplicaitonDelegate.  The Method -setNeedsDisplay is not found.

Trying `[self.window setNeedsDisplay]` gives no progress.

Directly calling the drawRect (which one doesn't want to do)  `CGRect rect = button.frame; [um drawRect:rect];` demonstrates the method present, logging is alive.

The resolution may be simple, but it escapes me.

Comment: Did you override the init method in UsableMark tomset the default frame? If not, the frame will have a zero size and the UIKit may skip displaying it as a performance operation.

Comment: Did override the initWithFrame.  But the init used was without it.
Have modified the code to use the initWithFrame. 
The initWithFrame is now called.  And so is drawRect !

Comment: Thanks.  drawRect is called.  Change your comment to an answer and I'll mark it.      Now to research the question as to why the drawRect drawing isn't visible.

Comment: The drawRect, once executed, didn't produce visible results because the frame provided in initWithFrame should have been a 0,0,button.frame.size.width, frame.size.height and not the frame.   That wound up with a double offset for the drawing, and given the button location, it was "off-screen".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that init is called instead of initWithFrame:. Since the default init was used, the view's frame had zero size, and UIKit skipped displaying it as an optimization.